# Random graph - probability threshold for any linear size set to contain a fixed clique

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, random-graphs

Let $t\geq 3$ and $0<\varepsilon<1$ be fixed. Denote by $K_t$ the clique on $t$ vertices, and by $G_{n,p}$ the binomial random graph.

**Question:**

> Is the threshold for the probability that "every subset of vertices of size $\varepsilon n$ contains a $K_t$" known ?

I expect it is. The required property is a logic second-order statement, but it is monotone, therefore the (sharp) threshold exists - I think this would follow from Bollobás and Thomason.

**Context:**
It is know that $p_{\subseteq}(n,t)= n^{-2/(t-1)}$ is the threshold for $G_{n,p}$ to contains $K_t$ as a subgraph.

Because the $2$-density of $K_t$ is $\frac{t+1}{2}$, is also follow from Rödl and Ruciński ([Threshold Functions for Ramsey Properties](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1995-08-04/S0894-0347-1995-1276825-6/)) that $p_{\to}(n,t)= n^{-2/(t+1)}$ is the threshold for $G_{n,p}$ to be Ramsey for $K_t$.

So the threshold for $G_{n,p}$ to be Ramsey for $K_t$, is the threshold for $G_{n,p}$ to contains $K_{t+2}$, which is not too surprising.
$$  p_{\to}(n,t) = p_{\subseteq}(n,t+2)$$

If we know consider the threshold $p_\varepsilon(n,t)$ for the property "every subset of vertices of size $\varepsilon n$ contains a $K_t$", a very quick analysis show that's we need $p_\varepsilon(n,t) $ to be at least the threshold for apperance of $K_{t+1}$, i.e. $p_{\subseteq}(n,t+1)$.

Indeed, if $p \ll n^{-2/t}$, a first-order argument shows that the expected number of cliques $K_t$ in $G\sim G_{n,p}$ is
$$ \mathbb{E}X \leq \left(\frac{e}{t}\right)^tn^\beta$$
with $\beta<1$. So we have a sub-linear expected number of $t$-clique.

But note that if there are $m$ cliques $K_t$ in $G\sim G_{n,p}$ such that each set of $(\varepsilon n)$ vertices contains a $K_t$, we have that,
$$ n-mt<\varepsilon n\Rightarrow m>\frac{1-\varepsilon}{t}n.$$
There is a linear number of cliques.

Therefore we have $p_\varepsilon(n,t) \geq p_\subseteq(n,t+1)$

I haven't though much about it except for this simple argument, and some very quick online research. I'm wondering if the actual threshold is known (I expect it is). It would be "nice" to have something as

- $n^{-2/(t-1)}$ : the threshold for appearance of $K_t$
- $n^{-2/t}$ the threshold for appearance of $K_{t+1}$ and for every linear-size subset contains a $K_t$
- $n^{-2/(t+1)}$ the threshold for appearance of $K_{t+2}$ and for the graph is Ramsey for $K_t$

But I'm not even convinced if the required property is stronger or weaker than being Ramsey for $K_t$